# Prevent injected tags from being affected by parent CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, jwplayer

I want to inject some HTML to another HTML page dynamically like this :

```
<div id="jwplayer-player"> ... </div>
```

In the parent HTML page, there is CSS rules for DIV as generic (This is sample , may be different according to the page) :

```
div {
    margin-top: 15px;
    line-height: 200%;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

How do I execlude my injected DIVs from being affected by them.

The player is injected as follows :

```
<div id ="vid-player-container" class="player-container"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="some.site.com/jwplayer/jwplayer.js" ></script>'); 
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="some.script.com/player_style1.js"></script>'); 
</script>
```

If I try it alone outside those parent pages, works perfectly.
So the key is isolating the injected code from being affected by the parent site, note that iFrame is not an option for me.

Comment: What's a parent HTML page?

Comment: I don't think that you can :( You could use the good old `!impartant` CSS indicator to specify styles that really need to be set a certain way.

Comment: @dana There are other possible ways, check my answer below as an example.

Comment: The parent page may be different each time.

Comment: AFAIK wrapping in an iframe prob is the only solution to this bar having more targetted styles applied to every selector or property in your markup - the C in CSS stands for cascading.Web Components also kind of take a step in the direction you want but browser support is still pretty average I believe.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use the ShadowDOM to achieve what you are trying to do. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM

It is designed to allow you to separate your components in this way, and provides isolation of CSS and JavaScript for the encapsulated DOM.

```
var shadow = document.querySelector('#container').attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
shadow.innerHTML += '<p>I am text in the injected code</p>'
```

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/rn46rfgx/

If you inspect element on your page, you should be able to see the isolation:

[image]

*Disclaimer* : Whilst this probably works for you, I'm not sure if it is the **correct** way to do this or if it's a bit of a "hack" - I hope others will comment on this answer with their thoughts on this!

Also, I'm not sure if the browser support will be adequate for you, you can check here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdom

Comment: !!!NOTE: please remember for now this only works in latest chrome and safari. other browser don't support it for now. BUT REALLY AWESOME SOLUTION.

Comment: If only the other browsers would catch up, eh ;). I was wondering if there are any polyfills which would be sufficient for this question but I think they tend to have limited CSS encapsulation. I might try it out when I have time.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to prevent the parent page from setting CSS styles, you should assume that any/all CSS styles that can be set by the parent page will be set.  Then, take the approach of specifying your own styles with a more specific selector.  In particular, you can use the `!important` indicator in combination with and id selector to have a reasonably good chance of having your style definitions win out.  For example:

```
<style type="text/css">
#jwplayer-player {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
    font-size: 100% !important;
    font: inherit !important;
    vertical-align: baseline !important;
    line-height: 1 !important;
}
</style>
<div id="jwplayer-player"> ... </div>
```

Note that I borrowed a good set of reasonable defaults from Eric Meyer's [Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: But there is CSS rules for the player I am injecting , I mean resetting will overwrite my injected css. Note that I dont know parent css, may be different each time.

Comment: Then you would modify the provided CSS snippet with your specific CSS rules. For example, if you could specify `margin: 10px !important;` or change the font. The key here is to be overly-specific when defining CSS rules.

Comment: I dont think specifying the css rules will solve the issue, the only solution is to isolate the injected div from being affected by parent's css and iFrame is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#jwplayer-player {
    margin-top: initial;
    line-height: initial;
    white-space: initial;
}
```

It will change all those rules to its initial values - default.

I am not sure if it will work in this case.

Comment: The issue is that the page may be different , I cant edit the parent page at all

Comment: maybe try this:
`<div id="jwplayer-player" style="margin-top: initial; line-height: initial; white-space: initial;">`

Comment: This is for specific parent page, how do I know other page's rules, I want my  code to be execluded form parent page css.

Comment: `<div id="jwplayer-player" style="all: default;"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`not`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp) CSS selector, update your `CSS` rule to become like this:

```
.MainContentdiv .BodyDiv :not(#jwplayer-player) div {
    margin-top: 15px;
    line-height: 200%;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: The issue is that the page may be different , I cant edit the parent page at all.

Comment: @BilalHalayqa Append this rule to the same page you're working on, and it should override the default in the parent page

Comment: I mean, this is for specific parent page, how do I know other page's rules

Comment: Add this CSS to the page you will add the `<div id="jwplayer-player"> ... </div>` tag, and that is it :)

Comment: It is not about adding the CSS, I dont want my div to be affected by parent, want it to be execluded.

Comment: This is how the `not` works, it will exclude all `divs` that are inside anything with id of `jwplayer-player`, have you tested it on your site?

Comment: But I dont want to change the parent page ! , actually I dont know it.

Comment: I am not asking you to change your parent page, and how don't you know it!! 

Just append the `CSS` to any of the files loaded into the page, and must do the trick

Comment: My html div is injected to other pages to show some video-ad there, there is no specific parent page, got me ?

Comment: How do you inject the `jwplayer`

Comment: like this :

<div  id ="vid-player-container" class="player-container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="some.site.com/jwplayer/jwplayer.js" ></script>');
 document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="some.script.com/player_style1.js"></script>');
</script>

Comment: Try this instead: `<div id ="vid-player-container" class="player-container"></div> <script type="text/javascript"> document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="some.site.com/jwplayer/jwplayer.js" ></script>'); document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="some.script.com/player_style1.js"></script>'); </script><style> .MainContentdiv .BodyDiv :not(#jwplayer-player) div { margin-top: 15px; line-height: 200%; white-space: normal; } </style>`

Comment: But ".MainContentdiv .BodyDiv" are related to this site, I may inject to another sites.

Comment: Then just use this part `:not(#jwplayer-player) div { margin-top: 15px; line-height: 200%; white-space: normal; }`